# Beamer: notes disappearing

Tags: beamer

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{xparse,tikz,pdfpc}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[<+->]
        \begin{theorem}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item A
                \note<.->[item]{A}
                \item B
                \note<.->[item]{B}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{theorem}
        \begin{theorem}
            C
            \note<.->[item]{C}
        \end{theorem}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When the second theorem is shown, the first two notes disappear. Why is that? I'd like to keep the notes local to where they are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that your default overlay specification not only acts on the main page, but will also cause the items on the note page to create new overlays, which brings them out of sync somewhere...

You can avoid this by switching back to normal overlay specification at the start of the note page:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=right}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}[<+->]
    \note{\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<*>}}
        \begin{theorem}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item A
                \note<.->[item]{A}
                \item B
                \note<.->[item]{B}
            \end{itemize}
        \end{theorem}
        \begin{theorem}
            C
            \note<.->[item]{C}
        \end{theorem}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, after reading a bit here on the site, I already assumed that that's the problem. But I didn't know the solution is actually so simple!